# Decode HResult = -2147467259

Tags: hresult

Can someone help me decode this HResult? What does it mean? I know the negative stands for a failure. How about the rest of the 10 bits?

I referenced MSDN HResult article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx), but I am not sure how to determine what my facility and code bits are.

More info:

> _message: "External component has thrown an exception."
>   Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}

Comment: I got this error when I attempted to post back some data which is more than usual. Can this be the source of error? Too much data?

Comment: Maybe. Hard to say. Can you post a [small, self-contained example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If so, post it here. Better yet, post a different question with that information.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question. I dug in further i found out the error was due to exceeding the maximium number of aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys. Increasing this number will fix the error.

Comment: For future use, I wrote an [HRESULT decoder](https://errorcodelookup.com/?q=-2147467259) that explains [how to decode this value](https://errorcodelookup.com/?type=hresult&code=80004005) (and any others).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I'll show you how to do it. Paste the negative number into Calculator (Windows) in programmer mode "Dec" setting. Then convert to "Hex" setting. You get the number: FFFFFFFF80004005. The error is 80004005 which is:

```
0x80004005
E_FAIL
Unspecified
```

Unfortunately the provider of the function that gave you this error did not categorize the error.

Useful links:

1. [MSDN - HRESULT Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx)
2. [MSDN - HRESULT Error List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx)

Comment: +1. A couple of notes for readers: (1) Make sure to include the minus sign, easiest way is to subtract the number from 0 and press `=` (2) If you have DWORD selected, it will strip out the redundant `FFFFFFFF` part for you.

Comment: Also, an even easier option for whoever missed Stephen Cleary's comment on the the question: https://errorcodelookup.com/?type=hresult&code=80004005

Comment: Very nice answer! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Print it as an hexadecimal number, then, use for instance, VisualStudio ErrorLookup, to get the message.

Comment: With Visual studio 2022 `it takes negative integers too.` It automatically converts the negative number to hex. Not sure if this is a recent feature or has it always been like this.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is as follows. An [HRESULT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) should contain a [System Error Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in its first 32 bits. Using an AND operation will retrieve the error code from the HRESULT:

```
int result = (-2147467259 & 0xFFFF)
```

`result` is 16389, which is not a part of the [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) list, and as a result, is unspecified.

Answer (score 3):

-2147467259 in decimal is 80004005 in hexadecimal (usually rendered as 0x80004005). That's ["E_FAIL (Unspecified error)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Win32.

Not a very helpful error code, but maybe it'll get you a half-step closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Decoding the error code with tools.

1. Visual Studio Error lookup tool ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/errlook-reference?view=msvc-170))
2. Microsoft Err.exe command line tool (standalone) ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool#usage)) ([download](https://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/2/432140e8-fb6c-4145-8192-25242838c542/Err_6.4.5/Err_6.4.5.exe))
3. Online utility - https://errorcodelookup.com

**1. Visual Studio Error lookup tool**

**Usage:**
[image]

**Locating the tool in Visual Studio (VS 2022):**

[image]

On my system it is present at the following location:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\errlook.exe"
```

**2. Microsoft Err.exe command line**

Microsoft also has a standalone commandline tool for decoding HRESULT errors: `Err.exe`. You need not install visual studio for this.

**Usage:**

```
PS C:\Users\j\Downloads> .\Err_6.4.5.exe 0x80004027
# for hex 0x80004027 / decimal -2147467225
  CO_E_CLASS_DISABLED                                            winerror.h
# The component or application containing the component has
# been disabled.
# 1 matches found for "0x80004027"
PS C:\Users\j\Downloads> .\Err_6.4.5.exe -2147467225
# for decimal -2147467225 / hex 0x80004027
  CO_E_CLASS_DISABLED                                            winerror.h
# The component or application containing the component has
# been disabled.
# 1 matches found for "-2147467225"
```

[image]

0x80004027 (-2147467225) is the error code above. As you can see it accepts both hex, and negative integers.

**3. Online utility - https://errorcodelookup.com**

The website allows you to decode error codes online.

eg. https://errorcodelookup.com/?q=0x80004027

[image]

*PS: The answer expands upon @BenjaminB's answer with some of my learnings. The error lookup tool is suggested in a comment by @Ohad Schneider.*