# What does ExitCode -1073741502 mean?

Tags: windows, api, exit-code

I'm using the GetExitCodeProcess API to determine the exit reason for a process.

When my process fails, I get the error code -1073741502.

How can this value be converted into a value that I could google for?

Thank you.

Edit: Well, 1073741502 appears on Google, but not -1073741502. Why does my error code have a minus?

Comment: `-1073741502` when printed as hexadecimal is `c0000142` which [according to this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/191991) means "DLL Initialization Failed". Please follow the link to read about the cause and possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HResult = -2147467259](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493524/decode-hresult-2147467259)

Comment: Incidentally, the output of GetExitCodeProcess is a `DWORD` which is `unsigned int`.  You must have accidentally printed it as `signed int` instead, that's why you get the minus sign.

Comment: -1073741502 doesn't appear on google because the minus prefix excludes a search term which in turn means you're searching for an empty string and thus don't get any results. If you wrap the number with quotes "-1073741502" you'll get results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Converted to hexadecimal, the value is 0xC0000142.
[Windows NTSTATUS values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) show that your error code is STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED which is:

> {DLL Initialization Failed} Initialization of the dynamic link library %hs failed. The process is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, return-codes consist of several bit-fields.  If I've done my math correctly, this translates to `0xffffffffc0000142` which probably consists of a group `0xc0000` and error-code `0x0142`.  If you're Googling for a code, also search for the hex string.

And, sure enough, that produces a hit.  There's even a StackOverflow entry that seems to directly address your problem:

[CreateProcess succeeds, but GetExitCodeProcess returns C0000142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425106/createprocess-succeeds-but-getexitcodeprocess-returns-c0000142)