# Windows docker container stops executing certain executables

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I have a Windows docker container (servercore) running on Windows, which works as expected. My entrypoint in docker executes a variety of commands in a row. At some point certain executables stop working and return with no output. Is there any chance to debug Docker or find out what is causing this behaviour? Example:

```
PS C:\tools> .\unzip.exe
PS C:\tools>
```

I tried executing `windbg`, but no success. I tried the powershell to access the event log, but I can't think of any proper way to tackle down this problem without having certain UI tools like `Process Monitor` (which also doesn't work) on cmd although it should (see below):

```
PS C:\tools> .\Procmon.exe /AcceptEula /Quiet /Minimized /BackingFile c:\temp\log.pml
PS C:\tools>
```

Python on the other hand works totally fine:

```
PS C:\tools> .\python.exe --version
Python 3.7.4
```

Update: The exit code of the applications which don't work is `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED` (What does ExitCode -1073741502 mean?)

There came another question in today with a similar question and problem: [How to start PowerShell (x86) in Windows Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271051/how-to-start-powershell-x86-in-windows-docker-container)

Comment: I found out that this is a bug in a recent Windows update on the host machine. After uninstalling the KB update, it works again. Thanks Microsoft ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a very similar issue when suddenly MSBuild stopped working and returned exit code `-1073741502` (aka `0xC0000142` / `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`).

Although probably not a satisfying answer, but at least a summary of the present state:

- Windows Server 1909 (OS Build 18363.**592**) - January 28, 2020 - [KB4532695](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4532695) - **works**
- Windows Server 1909 (OS Build 18363.**657**) - February 11, 2020 - [KB4532693](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4532693/windows-10-update-kb4532693) - **does not work**
- Windows Server 1909 (OS Build 18363.**693**) - February 27, 2020 - [KB4535996](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4535996) - **does not work**