# Which exceptions can StreamSocket.ConnectAsync throw?

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, uwp

To the moment, I found that if host name is invalid, I get Exception with HResult=-2147013895 and If the host name is OK but it refuses the connection attempt, I'm getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException with HResult=-2147014835. No InnerException is available. Because exception types are pretty generic, I'll have to catch Exception, analyse HResult and rethrow if this exception is not specific to network issues. Seems I need to find out which HResult codes to process in my code (all network-related) and re-throw anything else (out of memory and so on).

Is there any list of HResult codes which are specific to network issues? Or maybe there is another, better way to distinguish between network-specific and general exceptions which can be thrown during StreamSocket.ConnectAsync call?

Comment: Are you using same pc , to connect the server or client ?

Comment: My client and server are different machines now (I connect to an external host) but they can be the same machine as well.

Comment: Socket communcation : UWP application it wont work in same pc, it should be different pc

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your comment.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  . Check the Note section

Comment: This helps a bit although it's not clear how I can understand "now it's a socket error and I should process it in my code" or "it's not network error, it's something else and I should re-throw this exception to the caller".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130604/discussion-between-vinoth-rajendran-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493524/decode-hresult-2147467259), but if the error code isn't listed you are out of luck.

`-2147014835` [gives me](https://errorcodelookup.com/?type=hresult&code=88007274D)

> WSAECONNREFUSED (wrapped)
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

`-2147013895` [gives me](https://errorcodelookup.com/?type=hresult&code=80072AF9)

> WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND (wrapped)
>   No such host is known.

Further error codes can be listed here, but I included yours here. Perhaps you find a dedicated list for network and general exceptions, but that should give you a start.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this addresses my question.